Filament livewire asking for conponents.layouts.app in custom filament page
I am working on multi tenant e library system and filament for the admin dashboard everything is working fine but i want users to be able to edit site name and add descriptions and such so i created settings resource. Now my setting has three field ['key','value','type'] now eveything is set in the model so i went and tried to created custom page which will have name form field and description
use App\\Filament\\TenantAdmin\\Resources\\SettingsResource;
use App\\Models\\Settings;
use Filament\\Actions;
use Filament\\Forms\\Components\\Textarea;
  use Filament\\Forms\\Components\\TextInput;
  use Filament\\Forms\\Concerns\\InteractsWithForms;
  use Filament\\Resources\\Pages\\ListRecords;

   class ListSettings extends ListRecords 
   {
    use InteractsWithForms;

    protected static string $resource = SettingsResource::class;
    protected static string $view = 'filament.tenant-admin.resources.settings-resource.pages.settings-form';
    
    public function mount():void
    {
    $this->form->fill([
            'name' => Settings::where('key', 'name')->value('value'),
            'description' => Settings::where('key', 'description')->value('value'),
        ]);
    }
    
    protected function getFormSchema(): array
    {
        return [
            TextInput::make('name')
                ->label('Application Name')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255),
    
            Textarea::make('description')
                ->label('Site Description')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(500),
        ];
    }
    
    public function save()
    {
        $data = $this->form->getState();
    
        // Save settings
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            Settings::updateOrCreate(
                ['key' => $key],
                ['value' => $value, 'type' => 'string']
            );
        }
    
        $this->notify('success', 'Settings saved successfully!');
    }
    
    public function render(): \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
    {
        return view(static::$view, [
            'form' => $this->form->schema($this->getFormSchema()),
        ]);
    }

}

but as soon as that view loads it asks for components.layouts.app <- livewire is asking for it. if i create it im gona lose the panel navbar and all the widgets and it will render me new page
i tried creating the layout file but will just render me the page only.

what gives you the error "Livewire page component layout view not found: [components.layouts.app]" is the presence of the last function public function render() ...: if you comment it out it should work fine and show the page in your panel. The render() function is used for "Adding a form to a Livewire component" case (independent Livewire component), but not for adding a form to a custom Page that has to appear on the panel.
The view is already referenced in the declaration protected static string $view = ... and you should personalise that blade file in order to show the form, e.g. inserting:
<x-filament-panels::page>
  <x-filament-panels::form wire:submit="save">
     {{ $this->form }}
     <div>
       <x-filament::button type="submit" size="sm">Save</x-filament::button>
     </div>
  </x-filament-panels::form>
</x-filament-panels::page>

Moreover, instead of using protected function getFormSchema(): array  to create the form schema, you can use as in a regular form page:
public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                ...
            ]);
    }

So basically the idea is: Create a custom page in the panel as written in the docs, then add the form in the page as explained for the custom Livewire component, treating your custom page and its view as the Livewire component. It should be written more clearly in the documentation IMHO.
